# scanf expects one more value (VS Code)

Tags: c, scanf

I have a simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int alter;
    printf("Your age: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &alter);
    printf("your age is %d\n", alter);
}
```

Output is:

Your age: <entering some_number(1)> (**enter**)

*(terminal is waiting for another value)*

<entering some_number(2)> (**enter**)

your age is number(1)

why does it wait for me to enter 2 values?

thanks

Comment: what is the reason of the `\n` in the scanf format string

Comment: The incorrect `\n` in the `scanf` format string has to filter *any amount* of subsequent whitespace. So it is not until it receives a non-whitespace character (which will remain in the input buffer) that `scanf` can complete and return. Note that `scanf` does resemble `printf` but is very different in its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There should be be `\n` in the scanf. It should be

`scanf("%d", &alter);`

Comment: i didn't even notice, thank you..